# C# WebBrowser Control get form submit response

Tags: c#, forms, webbrowser-control

I have stumbled upon a problem that i really cant find the answer to, So im turning to stackoverflow for help.

I have just started using webbrowser control beacuse of a project im working on but i got all the way to send all the information. But i would like to recive the HTML that comes back after i have submited the form.

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
        wb.Navigate("https://example.com/query");

        while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) {                
            Application.DoEvents();
        }

        foreach (HtmlElement form in wb.Document.Forms)
        {
            form.InvokeMember("submit");
        }
```

I have used fiddler to trace the traffic after i submit and it all looks good all i need is just to get the updated website. Is that possible?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried WebBrowser "Navigated()" method to see if it receives the HTML?

Or maybe you can try "if(WebBrowser.Url.ToString() == "http://SomeWebsite/Received.html")" ?

I hope it gives you the solution or clue to your answer:)